# Table View Cell not showing if string assigned to a property is too long

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I am building an app that lets the user create a "Story" which consists of a title and a text.

I am implementing a tableView that shows all created stories. So far everything works. But here is my issue:

When the user enters a **title or text that is longer that what tableViewCell would be able to display, that cell doesn't show up at all**. 
Others with shorter names still do though.

I am using the cell style "subtitle".

**How does one go about limiting the amount of text showing in the cell and what causes this bug?** Because even if I find a way to fix it, there will probably still be a problem with text running off the screen.

Here is the code in my `UITableViewController` class:

```
class StoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return savedStories.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = savedStories[indexPath.row].title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = savedStories[indexPath.row].text
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the UI from the interface builder:

[image: Here is a screenshot of the UI from the interface builder]

Comment: So if user enter 1000 words for story and you wanted to show each word in that particular cell?

Comment: **Ideally only the first x characters.**

But my tableView currently doesn't show anything when the text is too long.

Comment: Add screen shot of ui.

Comment: Check my answer with output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your custom UITableViewCell. And you can use available dynamic resizable cells for adjusting cell automatically to text length.

IB steps:
Make a UILabel on cell. Don't give any height constraint to it. just pin it up from all sides and  do the followings :

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0 //Any estimated Height
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Don't write `heightForRow:` method but if you want to use it because of several cells existing there , you can return UITableViewAutomaticDimension for that particular cell height.

Try this one [out](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement these two delegates, don't forget to bind tableView delegate and datasource with VC and set you label description property `numberOfLines = 0` from storyboard.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return 60; // height of default cell
 }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension; // It takes automatic height of cell
}
```

**Now in storyboard do this below**

Your view hierarchy should be like this

[image]

check only ViewLabelContatainer

Add a view and put all labels into it.

**Label Container contraints**

[image]

**Label Title constraint**

[image]

**Label Description constraint**

[image]

> **output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use variable height TableViewCell

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{  
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200 // give maximum height you required
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

then add this delegate methode in your view controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```